# NETAPP - Enable on-box DNS load balancing in an Active Directory environment

Tags: active-directory, dns-zone, netapp, ontap

I have a NetApp Data Ontap 8.3 SP1 with 4 LIF.
LIF1 - 192.168.0.1
LIF2 - 192.168.0.2
LIF3 - 192.168.0.3
LIF3 - 192.168.0.4

There is a SVM, configured as NAPP0 and joined to an Active Directory domain( ad-domain.local) associated to LIF1 and in use.

In ADUC there is the relative computer account, in DNS exists both A record and PTR record for napp0 --> 192.168.0.1

Now I need to configure onbox dns load balancing; 
Easy task, create a DNS Zone delegation etc. (as per https://kb.netapp.com/support/index?page=content&id=1013801 ) BUT.... management asked me to use NAPP0 as the dns zone name......

What if I delete A record and PTR record for NAPP0, subsequently creating a zone delegation for NAPP0.AD-DOMAIN.LOCAL pointing to IPs(.1 .2 .3 .4)  leaving AD Computer object intact?

Comment: Are you having issues delegating napp0.addomain.local or is filer.napp0.ad-domain.local not resolving.

Comment: I am not an expert with this- I don't have it at my shop, but the way I remember it working, I think you're supposed to have a separate DNS entry for each individual LIF, and you can either use one of those or create one that's not a potential delegate just for joining the domain.

Comment: @Jim B no delegating a zone in dns is not a problem , I fear that delegating napp0.ad-domain.local  to ontap controller would disrupt active directory access for the appliance, as its registered in AD with a computer account name of Napp0 ...

Comment: @Basil yes i could do that, delegating round robin To dns server itself, but I need to have ontap doing that, as per management request... Unfortunately I cannot test in a lab environment ...

Comment: @Roberto, yes of course delegating the name (that would now be a zone) would disrupt access - that's what you said was a condition set on you by management.  You have been boxed in to where the netapp will be inaccessible due to whomever your management is, by insisting on a special zone name that exactly conflicts with the existing name

Comment: @Jim B - well, manager ego problems aside, I try to use **NAPP0-LB.ad-domain.local** as zone delegation name ; in this case there are no overlapping names. 

Can I then add all 4 IPs in DNS zone configuration?

I think that if I query DNS for NAPP0 I will get 192.168.0.1   and if I query DNS for NAPP0-LB then I will get one of the 4 IPs assigned , without access disruption ...

Please set your comment as a response as I can accept and upvote it. Thank you!